# Sort Array Date by Year and Month

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, date

I am trying to sort an array by Year and Month
this is my input:

```
var MyArray = ["2015-Jun", "2014-Nov", "2015-Dec", "2014-Aug", "2015-May"];
```

**I want this output:**

```
[ "2014-Aug", "2014-Nov", "2015-May", "2015-Jun", "2015-Dec" ]
```

I found this exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/Tw6xt/63/
It almost works. output:

```
2014-May,2015-Jun,2015-Dec,2014-Aug,2014-Nov
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/Tw6xt/64/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [setDate()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp) method that you are using sets the day of the month (1 to 31) and will give you some unexpected result since you pass a year "2015" to it.

wrong:
`ad.setDate(as[0]);`

What you need to do is use the [setFullYear()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp) method instead.

`ad.setFullYear(as[0]);`

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw6xt/65/

HTML

```
<div>Before sort: <span id="before"></span></div>
<div>After sort: <span id="after"></span></div>
```

JS

```
var MyArray = ["2015-Jun", "2014-May", "2015-Dec", "2014-Aug", "2014-Nov"];
document.getElementById("before").innerHTML = String(MyArray);

(function () {

    MyArray.sort(function (a,b) {
        var ad = new Date(),
        bd = new Date(),
        months = {
            Jan: 0, Feb: 1, Mar: 2, Apr: 3, May: 4, Jun: 5,
            Jul: 6, Aug: 7, Sep: 8, Oct: 9, Nov:10, Dec:12
        };

        var as = a.split('-'),
            bs = b.split('-');

        ad.setFullYear(as[0]);
        ad.setMonth(months[as[1]]);
        bd.setFullYear(bs[0]);
        bd.setMonth(months[bs[1]]);

        return ad - bd;
    });
})();

document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = String(MyArray);
```

OUTPUT

```
Before sort: 2015-Jun,2014-May,2015-Dec,2014-Aug,2014-Nov
After sort: 2014-May,2014-Aug,2014-Nov,2015-Jun,2015-Dec
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the sort to something like this:

```
MyArray.sort(function (a,b) {
    var as = a.split('-'),
        bs = b.split('-');
    if(parseInt(as[0])<parseInt(bs[0])){
        if(months[as[1]]<months[bs[1]])
            return -1;
        else if(months[as[1]]>months[bs[1]])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }else if(parseInt(as[0])>parseInt(bs[0])){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

This will first order by year then order by month, with output: 2014-May,2014-Aug,2014-Nov,2015-Jun,2015-Dec